# Manifest parsing error when uploading to Teams, but it has been validated by tools

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Trying to migrate to Typescript with a mostly empty app. Two basic default tabs and a bot.
Tackled the bot first since it has only two files and simple contents.

My .ts files are transpiled properly to .js ones and they are moved in a src/build folder.

However, when I try to upload the package to Teams, I'm getting a manifest parsing error.
The error, when copied to the clipboard, is as follows:

> Error while reading manifest.json: URL should start with "https://"

I validated the manifest using the built in VSCode toolkit, and it is fully validated as demonstrated here:
[image]

I used a JSON Diff to check that the manifest file in the zip and the manifest file before it is zipped / packaged have the same content. They do. Only change is the .env variables are replaced by proper URLs and data.

I've checked every URL in the manifest and they all start with https...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried uploading it a different way, like in App Studio in Teams for instance, or via the Apps pane in Teams? If those are also not working, perhaps you can paste a snippet of your manifest, with just the first parts of the addresses (so we can see better what's in use in your manifest, to try help)

Comment: Most problems in programming are between the chair and the screen, right? I had a similarly named folder and kept importing from the wrong .publish folder. Thanks for your quick answer, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most problems in programming are between the chair and the screen, right? I had a similarly named folder and kept importing from the wrong .publish location....

**Goes back to work, full of shame**